# Cannot use CComPtr (probably a linker issue)

Tags: visual-c++

I have 2 projects. I am trying to copy code from project A to project B. One of the lines, is

```
CComPtr<_CPH> _cphw = NULL;
```

This does not work in project B but works in project A. From what I can see this function is in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\atlmfc\include\atlcomcli.h.
I tried adding a #include, and read up that I needed to add the atl namespace but that doesn't help.

I'm not sure if its a linker issue because it works on one and not the other (I assumed linker was global).

this is my error

[image]

If it is a linker issue please advise how to resolve it. I would prefer to resolve in in VS over command line if possible.

Please give a brief explanation of how the linker works on a project level(if it does) i.e. where does it store the data for which folder to look in (optional)

Please help, Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to add `#include <atlbase.h>` and `using namespace ATL;`?

Comment: Also it looks like you have a syntax error in a `#define`. Please see this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ket47se8.aspx for more information.

Comment: I messed up I put #define<atlbase.h>... hey not my fault... I've been working for 12hrs straight.. need sleep.....or cofee

Comment: HAHA...should I delete this post?

Comment: Also please note those are not liker errors. They are compiler errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try to add the following:

```
#include <atlbase.h>
using namespace ATL;
```